# How to get a robust nonlinear regression fit using scipy.optimize.least_squares?

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares, non-linear-regression, robust

My specific issue is that I cannot seem to get my data to converted to floating points. I have data and simply want to fit a robust curve using my model equation:

> y = a * e^(-b*z)

This cookbook is my reference: [click](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/robust_regression.html)

Below is my attempt. I am getting this:

> TypeError: 'data type not understood'

which I believe is because my columns are strings, so I tried `pd.Series.astype()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

for i in range(1):

    def model(z, a, b):
        y = a * np.exp(-b * z)
        return y
    data = pd.read_excel('{}.xlsx'.format(600+i), names = ['EdGnd','380','395','412','443','465','490','510','520','532','555','560','565','589','625','665','670','683','694','710','Temp','z','EdZTemp','Tilt','Roll','EdZVin'])
    data.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'any')
    data.astype('float')
    np.dtype(data)
    data.plot.scatter('z','380') 
    def fun(x, z, y):
        return x[0] * np.exp(-x[1] * z) - y
    x0 = np.ones(3)
    rbst1 = least_squares(fun, x0, loss='soft_l1', f_scale=0.1, args=('z', 'ed380'))
    y_robust = model('z', *rbst1.x)
    plt.plot('z', y_robust, label='robust lsq')
    plt.xlabel('$z$')
    plt.ylabel('$Ed$')
    plt.legend();
```

Comment: What is `args=('z', '380')` supposed to do? Should the value `z` have the value `380`? Both are strings, so you cannot use it for multiplication. Could you provide a small dataset for debugging purposes?!

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! The arguments in least_squares are my x and y values that I want to get a fit for. Not sure why, but looking at the cookbook it seems that is what the author did. z is a depth and 380 is a wavelength of light. I'll try to get the strings into an array.

Comment: My data's length varies between different files to around 100-200 rows. It is 26 columns wide.Unfortunately, I can't upload the file.

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to use pd.Series.astype() to get my data as floating points. np.dtype() is saying: data type is not understood. This is my first time using pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you pass `'z'` in `args` which is a string and can therefore not be used in the multiplication.

Below is some code using [curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit) which uses `least_squares` but might be slightly easier to use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


# your model definition
def model(z, a, b):
    return a * np.exp(-b * z)

# your input data
x = np.array([20, 30, 40, 50, 60])
y = np.array([5.4, 4.0, 3.0, 2.2, 1.6])

# do the fit with some initial values
popt, pcov = curve_fit(model, x, y, p0=(5, 0.1))

# prepare some data for a plot
xx = np.linspace(20, 60, 1000)
yy = model(xx, *popt)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xx, yy)
plt.title('Exponential Fit')

plt.show()
```

This will plot

[image]

You could try to adapt this code for your needs.

If you want to use `f_scale` you can use:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(model, x, y, p0=(5, 0.1), method='trf', f_scale=0.1)
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit):

> kwargs
>
> Keyword arguments passed to leastsq for method='lm' or least_squares otherwise.

If you have an unbound problem, by default `method='lm'` is used which uses `leastsq` which does not accept `f_scale` as a keyword. Therefore, we can use `method='trf'` which then uses `least_squares` which accepts `f_scale`.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but I was going for the robust fit with least_squares because of the f_scale argument which does not allow influence from outlier data. Any way to eliminate outlier data with curve_fit?

Comment: @JacobCooper: It's possible to use `f_scale` in `curve_fit`; I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: @JacobCooper: You can also pass `sigma` to `curve_fit` (see the linked documentation for details).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much!